How to filter the one-to-many relationship from both side
I have two tables which has relationship.
class Parent(SafeDeleteModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1048,null=True,blank=True)

class Child(SafeDeleteModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1048,null=True,blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="parent_project")

In this case I can filter the Child by Parent such as
Child.objects.filter(parent__name__contains="test")

However I want to do the reverse like this below.
Parent.objects.filter(child__name__contains="test")

Is it possible?
I tried like this below
Parent.objects.filter(parent_project__contains="test")

however this error
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'contains' for ManyToOneRel or join on the field not permitted.


What shild I use for theplace child__name??

I am bit confused and my problem was may be because of contains I updated the article

You can set yourself as a foreign key through your own string.
class model(SafeDeleteModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1048,null=True,blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="children"
    )

# Model whose parent name is a
model.objects.filter(parent__name='a')
# Select only the parent model
model.objects.filter(parent=None)
# Model with child name b (related name set to children)
model.objects.filter(children__name='b')
# Model with c in child name (related name is set to children)
model.objects.filter(children__name__contatins='c')


I understood and it works, maybe I should replace the related_name as appropriate name.

few notes:

your model should inherit models.Model
the first parameter of the ForeignKey should point to Parent not Project if the relationship is between parent and child.

Then you can query using related_name:
Parent.parent_project.filter(name="child name")

Thank you very much, I updated the article , Project -> Parent my misstypo and model inherit models.Model

if you want this Parent.objects.filter(child__name__contains="test")  to work just add related_query_name = child as a parameter
helpful resources  related_name and related_query_name
